# Android Place.getLocale() returns null

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using the place picker from Android google places SDK to get addresses. The place picker returns addresses just fine, I'm able to get the address, the LatLng, but when I try to get the country name through locale it returns null!

Here's my code snippet:

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment mAddressEditText = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.address);
mAddressEditText.setHint("Address");
mAddressEditText.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place)
    {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.d(TAG, "Place selected");
        mAddressOK = true;
        mAddress = place.getAddress().toString();
        mLocation = place.getLatLng();
        mCountry = place.getLocale().getDisplayCountry();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status)
    {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.d(TAG, "Invalid Place Selected.");
        mAddressOK = false;
        invalidAddressDialog.show();
    }
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.Locale.getDisplayCountry()' on a null object reference
```

I've verified that the place.getLocale() returns null through a Log.d check. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getLocale()) doesn't specify that the function call could return null and I'm not sure why this is happening.

## EDIT1:

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getAddress()) the Place class internally uses locale to format the address. so how come getLocale return null?!

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to use `GeoCoder` for getting the country Name or similar info about the place. As you have the `LatLng` now you can make a `GeoCoder` object.

```
LatLng coordinates = place.getLatLng(); // Get the coordinates from your place
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
            coordinates.latitude,
            coordinates.longitude,
            1); // Only retrieve 1 address
Address address = addresses.get(0);
```

Then you can call these methods to get the informations you want

```
address.getCountryCode();
address.getCountryName();
```

More methods on the Address objects : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html](http://More%20methods%20on%20the%20Address%20objects%20:%20http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)

Comment: Thank you. This works. I still don't get why getLocale returns null though!